# How to fill an array using Firestore Objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to make a e-book Application Using Firebase and Firestore .
Here is how the database looks like :

```
books
      Book1
             -title:abc
             -category:123 
             -description:123
      Book2 
             -title:xyz
             -category:456
             -description:123
```

so basically i need to retrieve data from Firebase-firestore and put them in an array ( i called him lstBook ) , so here is my code that i have tried but it haven't worked ( Nothing shown at the MainActivity )

```
List<book> lstBook;

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("books");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    notebookRef.addSnapshotListener(MainActivity.this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null){
                return;
            }

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                BookActivity note = documentSnapshot.toObject(BookActivity.class);

                String title = note.getTvtitle();
                String description = note.getTvdescription().toString();

            }
            lstBook.add(new book(title,"test","",R.drawable.themartian));
        }
    });
}
```

i am using cardView and RecyclerView but i can add books Basically (Manual) by adding this code

```
lstBook.add(new book("Book Title","Category","Description",Image here));
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate if the `BookActivity` class is the model class for the documents in your `books` collection. In this way I'll be able to give you a straight answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    notebookRef.addSnapshotListener(MainActivity.this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null){
                return;
            }

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){

                String title = documentSnapshot.get("tvtitle").toString();
                String description = documentSnapshot.get("tvcategory").toString();

                lstBook.add(new book(title,"test",description,R.drawable.themartian));

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i havent understand override the toString() . Searched and found that i need to press Ctrl + O in android Studio and Import it in BookActivity.class but still nothing shown in the MainActivity while Testing

Comment: Try to do log of title and description inside for loop and let me know if they are retrieved successfully or not ?

Comment: So it should Looks like Log.i("KeyData", title + description); . i need to launch the app and go to Logcat

Comment: Yeah thats correct. add a space title + " " + description to see data in a proper format.

Comment: @zakariakhalil have you allow the rules ?

Comment: @Zuhrain that was missing too TY i fixed it ^^